# Using curl to grab Yahoo Groups

Tags: php, api, curl, yahoo-api

I have found an API for Yahoo Groups which I would like to use to pull in the Last 100 posts to a group in JSON format. I have not used an API before but my research has shown that using curl is the best way to get the api data programmatically (I plan to write a function in php to do this later).

When I use the API in a browser is works fine,
     https://groups.yahoo.com/api/v1/groups/glastonburynoticeboard/messages?count=100&sortOrder=desc&direction=-1

but when I try to use curl in terminal

curl https://groups.yahoo.com/api/v1/groups/glastonburynoticeboard/messages?count=100&sortOrder=desc&direction=-1

I get the following error :
User does not have READ permission for MESSAGE. Me...","errorCode":1101

How do I get read permission when I don't need to do anything in the browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I access that URL in the browser, I'm asked for authentication. So it would appear that you're already authenticated in your browser and that's why it works (try it in a private browsing window, it should ask you for authentication then too).

I'm guessing https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-signing.html has the information you need.

Comment: Of course I was logged into Yahoogroups in the browser. Thanks, much appreciated.